# didn't check the character between the numbers in numeric validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The following function is used to numeric validation alone.If I copy and paste the string "123we" it will paste 123.

But my problem is if I copy "123we23q" it will paste like 123we23.Only the last digit is removed and **didnt check the character between the numbers**

```
$( "input[type=text]" ).on("keyup", function() {
  var o=$(this);
  o.val(o.val().replace(/[^\d]/g,""));
});
```

Comment: try using onblur instead of keyup.might work

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3TSFR/1/

Comment: You said "Only the last digit is removed" - did you mean "Only the last non-digit is removed"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly

```
<input type="text">
```

check this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/shyamchandranmec/vLnqj/